# Perl :: Unable to fork 32000 processes

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script which fork 32000 processes and each processes perform a bunch of operation for 24 hours. But I am unable to fork that many processes. Any workaround? Please note,the code works perfectly fine for fewer number of processes. Here is the error which I am getting:

```
pty_allocate(nonfatal): posix_openpt(): No space left on device at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Pty.pm line 24.
pty_allocate(nonfatal): getpt(): No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Pty.pm line 24.
pty_allocate(nonfatal): getpt(): No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Pty.pm line 24.
pty_allocate(nonfatal): openpty(): No such file or directory at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Pty.pm line 24.
pty_allocate(nonfatal): open(/dev/ptmx): No space left on device at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Pty.pm line 24.
```

Comment: There has to be a better way to do what you're doing than forking 32000 processes.

Comment: Its a sort of stress testing of the application. The application supports at max 32000 instances.

Comment: Does it work with 31999?

Comment: No, the lower limit I got was something around 500

Comment: What's the result of `ulimit -u` when you type that into your terminal?

Comment: This might help:
https://superuser.com/questions/559709/how-to-change-the-maximum-number-of-fork-process-by-user-in-linux

Comment: OK, so that's the result of your stress test -- it supports around 500.  In that environment, that is. The messages show that you are running out of (other) resources.

Comment: I increased it upto 500000

Comment: @user3686233 what does it return when you type `ulimit -u` though?

Comment: I have set ulimit as 500000

Answer (score 6):

Your issue isn't with Perl, it's an operating system limitation.  Your kernel only allows the allocation of a finite number of ptys, and this is a global (system-wide) limit, not a per-user or per-process limit.

Assuming you are running under Linux, `man 7 pty` tells us that

> In kernels up to and including 2.6.3, this  limit  is configured  at 
>   kernel  compilation  time (CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS), and the permitted
>   number of pseudoterminals can be up to 2048, with  a  default setting 
>   of  256.   Since  kernel  2.6.4,  the  limit  is  dynamically
>   adjustable via  /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max,  and  a  corresponding 
>   file, /proc/sys/kernel/pty/nr,  indicates  how  many pseudoterminals
>   are currently in use.

Thus, if you're using a relatively recent (2.6.4 or later) Linux kernel, you should be able to use `cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max` to see your system-wide maximum pty count.

According to [this document](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-increase-pty-session.html) (I have not tried it myself to verify), you should be able to change the limit by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding the line `kernel.pty.max = 5120` (or whatever number), then using `sysctl -p` to reload the sysctl configuration.

But note that each pty requires the allocation of other system resources (memory, file handles, etc.), so increasing the maximum ptys to an arbitrarily large number may do Very Bad Things to the rest of the system.